# How to transform milliseconds into seconds .?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have to transform my Stopwatch "Variable" into seconds ?

```
Stopwatch czasAlg = new Stopwatch(); 
czasAlg.Start();
//Do semothing
czasAlg.Stop();
Decimal Tn = czasAlg.ElapsedMilliseconds/(decimal)n;
```

Comment: Seriously.. you don't know how to transform milliseconds into seconds? :o

Comment: But... why go through the extra step? :-)

Answer (score 44):

Divide by 1000 or use

```
czasAlg.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 25):

Without your own constants and magic numbers:

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: What is the difference of .Seconds and .TotalSeconds on TimeSpan?

Comment: `.Seconds` gets the seconds place of the TimeSpan. So if it was 1 minute and 30 seconds you would get `30` back where `.TotalSeconds` would return `90`.

Comment: Use TimeSpan.Duration() to get the absolute value of the timespan. `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x).Duration().TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 24):

Just to be different:

Multiply by 0.001.

Comment: That'll scare the other developers!

Comment: Hm, evil idea: `double.Parse(string.Format("{0}e-3", czasAlg.ElapsedMilliseconds))`

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
czasAlg.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 2):

How about 1s = 1000ms

http://www.google.com/search?q=milliseconds+to+seconds&btnG=Google+Search&aq=0&oq=milliseconds+

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1000.0?

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using math and multiplying/diving like this: seconds (60) * 1000 = 60000, use TimeSpan instead, it's using bit operations, and due to it has a minimum cost of performance.

### Milliseconds to seconds

```cs
int sixtyThousandsMillisecondsInSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60000).TotalSeconds;
// Outputs 60
```

### Seconds to milliseconds

```cs
// 1 min (60 seconds) in milliseconds = 60000 (i.e 60 * 1000)
int sixtySecondsInMilliseconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds;
// Outputs 60000
```

### Using LINQPad

```cs
int sixtyThousendsMillisecondsInSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60000).TotalSeconds;
sixtyThousendsMillisecondsInSeconds.Dump();

int sixtySecondsInMilliseconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds;
sixtySecondsInMilliseconds.Dump();
```

#### Results

60

60000